Heat pump COP big differences between manufacturers
I've compored multiple brands, and it turns out that LG Therma has the best COP in low temperatures.
For example:
12kW LG claims COP of 2.35/55C in -10C
Midea 12kW claims only 1.79/55C,
the same with Panasonic - 1.84/55C
or Aiwa - 1.79/55C.
All of them are R32 based monoblocks with supposedly the same compressor type - scroll.
Is it possible that LG is far more better then others, or are they lying in their specs?
They claim that Therma 12kW achives COP of 1.8/55C in -20C!
Only their split version achives comparable COPs to the rest of manufactures (COP 1.77/55C in -10C)

COP is based on structured tests. Actual performance will vary according to conditions. If you want the "best" cop performance then every part has to be matched to the conditions and themes precise sensors and control systems need to be used.

So it is possible that LG tweaked their heat pump to be good in lab enviroment, and in reality they would have the same specs like any other manufacturer ?
None of the manufacturers I've looked didn't give any info regarding the conditions in which they have tested their products.

I'm sure LG has documents which give that detail. If concerned, ask for them. I didn't bother going to that level if detail; I found an installer I trusted and let them recommend make and model and configuration, and energy savings have been much more than sufficient.

It might be enlightening to check the physical dimensions and configuration of these competing models. If the LG has a dual fan or a heat exchanger with a larger area, this could account for the better cold weather performance that they claim.
